# Bit Shifting with units of measure in F#

Tags: f#, units-of-measurement

I have three types of position - called Position, WalkPosition and TilePosition. I've converted them to units of measure, and it is much cleaner, but some things just don't quite work for me.

Unfortunately, I'm not using purely F# (there's a C++ interface exposed via CLI - fun times!). Firstly, for converting in and out, I've used * 1<tile> and * 1<1/tile> because I noticed a performance hit on my use of int. That's all well and good until I start trying to do interesting things with generics. I'm currently stumped by the getApproxDistance function, with an operator I'm calling |~|. This version assumes no unit of measure attached to my Position:

```
[<Measure>] type pixel
[<Measure>] type walk
[<Measure>] type tile

module Position =
    type Position<[<Measure>] 'u> = Pos of int<'u> * int<'u> with
        static member inline (+) (Pos (x1, y1), Pos (x2, y2)) = Pos (x1 + x2, y1 + y2)
        static member inline (-) (Pos (x1, y1), Pos (x2, y2)) = Pos (x1 - x2, y1 - y2)
        static member inline (*) (Pos (x, y), f) = Pos (x * f, y * f)
        static member inline (/) (Pos (x, y), d) = Pos (x / d, y / d)
        // getApproxDistance as per Starcraft: Broodwar
        static member (|~|) (Pos (x1, y1), Pos (x2, y2)) =
            let xDist = abs (x1 - x2)
            let yDist = abs (y1 - y2)
            let largeDist, smallDist = max xDist yDist, min xDist yDist
            if smallDist < (largeDist >>> 2) then largeDist
            else
                let smallCalc = (3*smallDist) >>> 3
                ((smallCalc >>> 5) + smallCalc + largeDist - (largeDist >>> 4) - (largeDist >>> 6))
        // Precise length calc - may be slow
        static member inline (|-|) (Pos (x1, y1), Pos (x2, y2)) =
            pown (x1 - x2) 2 + pown (y1 - y2) 2 |> float |> sqrt

    let inline posx (Pos (_x, _)) = _x
    let inline posy (Pos (_, _y)) = _y

    let PixelPerWalk : int<pixel/walk> = 8<pixel/walk>
    let PixelPerTile : int<pixel/tile> = 32<pixel/tile>
    let WalkPerTile : int<walk/tile> = 4<walk/tile>

    let inline walkToPixel (pos:Position<_>) = pos * PixelPerWalk
    let inline tileToPixel (pos:Position<_>) = pos * PixelPerTile

    let inline pixelToWalk (pos:Position<_>) = pos / PixelPerWalk
    let inline tileToWalk (pos:Position<_>) = pos * WalkPerTile

    let inline pixelToTile (pos:Position<_>) = pos / PixelPerTile
    let inline walkToTile (pos:Position<_>) = pos / WalkPerTile

    let example = Pos (1<walk>, 2<walk>) |~| Pos (2<walk>, 1<walk>)
```

I'd be content to rip the unit of measure off (|> int doesn't seem to slow it down in this scenario) and add it back on the returned distance, but it seems I can't do that. I can't even overload an inline call, because you can't overload purely on units of measure. Ideas?

Comment: You say you can't overload on units of measure. In some cases it works, what would you like to overload? Can you show a (non-working) sample code?

Comment: It's unclear to me what exactly is the problem. The code above compiles so I assume it's something else?

Comment: Added an example that fails at the bottom and illustrates why the type signature is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error that you are seeing is because the units of measure in your `|~|` function are being constrained to `1`.  This means that an `int<walk>` is not a valid input to this function.

You are correct that the `int` function will strip units of measure from something of type `int<'u>`.  What you may not be aware of is that you can use `LanguagePrimitives.Int32WithMeasure<'u>` to add a particular unit of measure.

You can therefore write `|~|`:

```
static member (|~|) (Pos (x1 : int<'u>, y1 : int<'u>), Pos (x2 : int<'u>, y2 : int<'u>)) =
    let xDist = abs (int x1 - int x2)
    let yDist = abs (int y1 - int y2)
    let largeDist, smallDist = max xDist yDist, min xDist yDist
    if smallDist < (largeDist >>> 2) then 
        largeDist 
        |> LanguagePrimitives.Int32WithMeasure<'u> 
    else
        let smallCalc = (3*smallDist) >>> 3
        ((smallCalc >>> 5) + smallCalc + largeDist - (largeDist >>> 4) - (largeDist >>> 6))
        |> LanguagePrimitives.Int32WithMeasure<'u>
```

Your example:

```
let example = Pos (1<walk>, 2<walk>) |~| Pos (2<walk>, 1<walk>)
```

This then has the correct type: `int<walk>`.

You shouldn't need to worry about the performance impact of stripping away/adding units of measure, they are just a compile time construct - unit of measure information is not retained at runtime.

By the way, you also don't really need all of those `inline` keywords everywhere, you aren't doing anything with statically resolved type parameters, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548047.aspx for more detail about use of `inline`.

Comment: I have had some performance improvements for inlining and avoiding int casts to remove units of measure. For the first case, your link says "inline functions can be helpful in optimizing code" in a way that isn't totally obvious. For the second case, it's clearly documented that this should have no effect. I don't have a clear example to present.